# wget and axel could not download link with have any parenthesis

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, wget

if download links having any parenthesis wget and axel could not download it. for example this link:

```
alachiq@alachiq:~$ wget http://dl2.downloadha.com/Animation/November%202011/15/Rango%20Farsi%20(www.Downloadha.com).rar

bash: syntax error near unexpected token (
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to either escape them or surround the entire URL in quotes:

```
wget http://dl2.downloadha.com/Animation/November%202011/15/Rango%20Farsi%20\(www.Downloadha.com\).rar
# OR
wget "http://dl2.downloadha.com/Animation/November%202011/15/Rango%20Farsi%20(www.Downloadha.com).rar"
```

The reason for this is that, in most advanced shells (`bash`, in your case), parenthesis are special characters for sub-shells, substitutions, Arrays, and other features. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/bash-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces).